# Need to make htaccess rule that blocks empty user agent unless the request contains a specific string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to block empty user agents for bad-bot reasons. So I had this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Now one of our customers uses an RSS aggregator whose request for his feed comes in as a "-" user agent... So I'm trying to add a condition to this rule that says "if the request does not contain /feed" then block the access... So this is the main thing I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)(/feed)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

But the request is still getting blocked. I know it's just this rule set blocking it because if I comment it out then the request comes through fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the URL of your feed? On a side note, change the second line to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feed` since that's equivalent to what you've got there anyway. It means "/feed" anywhere in what it's matching against. Regexes don't have to match the whole thing. What you have is not a problem, just not necessary.

Comment: Ok, so I replaced that second line with what you posted, but I still get this line in the access log when I try to load the feed with the aggregator:

"GET /en/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 403 218 "-" "-"

If I comment out all 3 lines, it loads fine in the aggregator.

Comment: Oh and the feed is either accessed by: domain.com/en/feed, or for a personalized version, domain.com/en/feed/?a=whatevertheusertokenishere

Comment: I have no idea what to suggest. It looks all perfect to me. Perhaps post your full config in case something unusual is amiss.

Comment: Actually what you can do, if you have access to the main server config, is specify `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` then you will see in the error log exactly what is happening when the directives are processed. Please post that.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for that tidbit, learning something new about server admin stuff everyday. I pasted the output here: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/3A8O

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log makes it clear. You have another rewrite which is rewriting /en/feed to /index.php and it is /index.php that is then getting the forbidden response. Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/en/feed
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

(adding the L flag, I also improved the second line to target the feed URL only)

And put it before your other rewrites.

Comment: Hmm so it was before all the other rewrites, and it's still blocking it. I think it has something to do with it being on a Wordpress site. If I end all the other rewrites it can't access the code to make the RSS feed... 

I think that technically your answer is what I need, but unfortunately wordpress makes it more complicated than that. :(

Comment: WordPress is just code like any other, I'm sure this can be achieved. You're not ending the other rewrites, only for ones with successful matches of the whole thing, the ones that are getting forbidden, not the feed ones that didn't match the whole thing.

Comment: There must be some WordPress rewrites happening before this, the logs show it, have a good look at your server config and .htaccess files. Where do you have the code? Perhaps share your whole config in the question.

Comment: Figured it out! The rewrite needed to go after the default wordpress rewrite chunk so that wordpress could route to the feed properly and then use the rules. Accepting your answer, although I didn't use the != I just used !

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Good stuff. You should use the =, it makes it an exact match. Otherwise it will match any URL with /en/feed in it, anywhere at all, rather than being only that. So if you had a page, or add one later, with a URL /blah/en/feeding-cats that would be allowed with no user agent. If you don't want to use the = you should use ^/en/feed$ but the equals is better for legibility.